# CSS/Fonts : Getting very different results than expected compared to live sites

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've been having this problem for a while now, but I notice a lot of websites seem to have a very ... it is hard to explain, their fonts have a sort of "strength" to them. Like a bold, crisp, sharp definition. For example, I cite this page:

## [CSS-TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/)

[image]

The way it looks comes out beautiful; Even the image that I embedded here does not do it justice. Spending time, I traced the exact font, exact settings, EXACT everything - I tried to reproduce it, but I get a COMPLETELY different result, even in the same browser.

Using the same font, same size, same everything I know of to match, this is how it looks on my end.

[image]

The specific code I am matching is the font, sizing, weight, and line height; which is;

```
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700,400italic";

html {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

I have attempted to dig deeper, and using FireFox I found a bit more context, I tried emulating that as well with some more specific code it serves up; Which is...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Noto Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Noto Sans"), local("NotoSans"), url("http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/notosans/v4/LeFlHvsZjXu2c3ZRgBq9nD8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff") format("woff");
}
```

But that continues to deliver the same results.

This is true of almost every time I have ever tried to reproduce that crisp feeling from production websites - and I literally have no idea what is going on. Can anyone explain to me why my fonts never match up with these sites, even using the same code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Firebug, can you confirm that the @import CSS is actually being fetched over the network?

Here's what the Firebug console looked like for me when I tried this in a simple test page that rendered the font just fine on my system: (I'm not allowed to post images yet but you can see the screen shot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJODq.png)

Here is the HTML I was testing with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700,400italic";

        html {
            font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
            line-height: 1.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Hello, world
</body>
</html>
```

The other thing you might want to check is if it's browser-specific, i.e. does this work okay with Chrome?

Comment: I can confirm that the font is being fetched, and it gives me the same result in every browser that I try. This happens no matter what the font, even fonts that I download and load locally.

Comment: The problem is not getting the font - the problem is that the font just _looks_ different than it does on the page I see. When I use it, it is like a completely different font than what I see on the other published sites.

Comment: One other thought I had - maybe try setting font-weight: 400 in your CSS? I wonder if your system and mine have different defaults. The Google fonts declaration declares the weight at 400 so perhaps you have to explicitly set that.

Comment: I've examined that as well, with no results.

Comment: Hey, after further working on this, it turns out that the font was just not up to date in google's repository. I was getting bad files. apparently this has now been rectified, as things are starting to load correctly.